# i am trying to fetch an image which is stored in database in a page but i am unable to do so in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to fetch an image which is stored in database in a page but i am unable to do so in laravel.
i am storing the hashed value of image ...
here is where i am trying to fetch an image from the database

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
    <td> <img src="{{$post->image}}" alt=""> </td> 
    <td>
        {{$post->title}}
    </td>
    </tr>  

    @endforeach

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

i have also linked my storage file

```
php artisan storage:link
```

here is the code in my store method of controller

```
 public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {

      $image= $request->image->store('posts');

        Post::create([
          'title'=>$request->title,
           'description'=>$request->description,
           'content'=> $request->content,
          'image'=> $image

        ]);

        session()->flash('success','Post Created Successfully.');

      return redirect(route('posts.index'));
  }
```

when i tried to load image in the page which is index.blade.php 
all i see is this 
[image: how i can show my image in this table]

Comment: Is the complete image stored in your database or just the path to the image?

Comment: in my database path to the image is stored in hashed value such as posts/1fYgRaxeEz5WTi64z5Z4RVHsOZ1HoXwz5jcVJPwo.jpeg

Comment: Showing the output of your code would be far more helpful than pictures.

Comment: i am trying to post image in my page so in a sense image is my output of code .

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
    {

      $image= $request->image->store('posts');

        Post::create([
          'title'=>$request->title,
           'description'=>$request->description,
           'content'=> $request->content,
          'image'=> \Storage::url($image);

        ]);

        session()->flash('success','Post Created Successfully.');

      return redirect(route('posts.index'));
  }
```

Comment: Instead of this, you can also try  <td> <img src="{{ \Storage::url($post->image) }}" alt=""> </td> , It above works then this will also work.

Comment: <td> <img src="{{ \Storage::url($post->image) }}" alt=""> </td> tried this also image is still not showing .

Comment: Try accessing the image url (that is printed in DOM by inspecting the img) in your browser, and see what is wrong.

Comment: And also check if the image file is being created in your storage folder.

Comment: yes i can see the image in the storage folder . but when i open my browser in developer mode here i am seeing this error

Comment: Failed to load resource:1fYgRaxeEz5WTi64z5Z4RVHsOZ1HoXwz5jcVJPwo.jpeg:1  the  the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you provide the url that you have got?

Comment: posts/EaqhkhYefs7JZXZy2kEzUcZCVPajHY1Wn3VCORrk.jpeg. this is link i got when i tried to display the image using {{$post->image}}

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)